# BeautifulSoup Python saving Output links to txt file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use BeautifulSoup to gather links off a webpage.  So far I have been able to do this and print them off in the command prompt using a print command that is commented out of the code currently.  The problem I am running into is when the links are saved to the Output.txt file, they all override each other and only the last link is saved.  Any help is most appreciated!

If you have any pointers on making this transition all in one program see my end goal.
***My end goal is to then search through the links in the txt file to determine if it has specific text in them.  If they do, I want to return "Broken Link" or "Not Broken".***

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc) #html doc is source code for website i am using

for link in soup.find_all(rel="bookmark"):
  Gamma =(link.get('href'))
  f =open('Output.txt','w')
  f.write(Gamma)
  f.close()
  #print(Gamma)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open up the file for writing before the loop and call `write()` inside:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

with open('Output.txt','w') as f:
    for link in soup.find_all(rel="bookmark"):
        f.write(link.get('href'))
```

Also, note that using [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) helps here not to worry about closing the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it "append" mode, by replacing "w" for "a".

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc) #html doc is source code for website i am using

for link in soup.find_all(rel="bookmark"):
  Gamma =(link.get('href'))
  f =open('Output.txt','a')
  f.write("{gamma}\n".format(gamma=Gamma))
  f.close()
  #print(Gamma)`enter code here`
```

Comment: This is a _bad_ idea. Opening and closing the file inside the loop like that adds a _lot_ of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need to append your file.  Also its more efficient to to do a single open and close.

```
f = open ('Output.txt', 'a')
for link in soup.find_all(rel="bookmark")
   Gamma =(link.get('href')
   f.write(Gamma + '\n')
f.close()
```